# No bounding boxes showing up

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I've followed a tutorial on running a novel dataset with the object_detection API. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9

It seemed to go just fine, the training is running just fine with loss decreasing over time, but the problem is with the eval.py. If I try to run evaluation (as described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) I get a few issues. First, I get this message:

```
WARNING:root:The following classes have no ground truth examples: 0
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide num_images_correctly_detected_per_class / num_gt_imgs_per_class)
```

There are a few unaddressed issues on the GitHub page for this problem: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1936

However, I have a possible related extra issue. When I open tensorboard to display the evaluation, under the Images tab it generates, I see NO bounding boxes whatsoever. Also, it displays "image-9" as a title, but if I use the slider to slide through steps it is actually changing images instead of showing a bounding box learning over time. I'm very confused by this. Please help!

Comment: Same issue. I am using tensorboard 2.5.0. Please some one help.